# Minted set manual hyphenation

Tags: hyphenation, minted

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[breaklines, tabsize=2]{perl}
  $mech->agent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0');
  $mech->get("http://turizm.user.control.new1.dev.website-url.com/hotels/save_add_hotel/");
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Extra shift was added, though no hyphenation. Is it possible to manually tell minted where to split the line like it did for Firefox, using space? The arrow is somehow related to tabulation of the string, but it is necessary for the code.

Comment: You might try something like `breakafter=/` to enable other break locations besides spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `minted` only breaks lines at spaces. You can allow any break location with `breakanywhere`, or specify characters at which to break with `breakbefore` and `breakafter`. In this case, something like `breakafter=/` would probably work well.